# Unzip a password protected zip file with Apache ant?

Tags: ant, passwords, unzip

Is there a way to unzip a password protected zip file directly with ant?

Currently I'm calling an external zip tool. But I would prefer an ant-only solution as it does not require any extra tools.

(And yes, I do have the password.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one seems to have got around to it yet - there is an [Ant bugzilla ticket](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24167) for it.  As the ticket says, there are a number of potential pitfalls to implementing a general solution.